# How To find overlapping Dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a table which has startdatetime and enddatetime. how to find the the particuler datetime which is overlapping in other dates:
see below example

```
create table #period (
    id int,
    starttime datetime,
    endtime datetime
  );

insert into #period values 
(1,'2013-10-10 08:00:00' , '2013-10-10 10:00:00'), 
(2,'2013-10-10 08:10:00' , '2013-10-10 08:20:00'), 
(3,'2013-10-10 08:10:00' , '2013-10-10 08:30:00') 
(4,'2013-10-10 08:15:00' , '2013-10-10 08:25:00') 

select * from #period


required output is '2013-10-10 08:15:00' , '2013-10-10 08:20:00' is getting overlapped in all the dates.

expected output: '2013-10-10 08:15:00' '2013-10-10 08:20:00' 5 Min
```

**EDIT:**

I apologies for previous question 
Here it is the proper details with example

```
create table #period 
(
    Sitecode varchar(20),
    svrname varchar(10),
    StartTime datetime,
    downtimeEnd datetime
) 
go  

insert into #period values 
('A','S1','2013-10-10 10:00:00' , '2013-10-10 11:00:00'), 
('A','S2','2013-10-10 10:00:00' , '2013-10-10 11:00:00'),
('A','S3','2013-10-10 10:00:00' , '2013-10-10 11:00:00'), 
('A','S1','2013-10-10 03:00:00' , '2013-10-10 03:30:00'), 
('A','S2','2013-10-10 06:30:00' , '2013-10-10 07:30:00')

select * from #period
```

Expected Output is:

> ```
> Sitecode 'A' 
>        Total 2.5 hours (below is the details)
>        '2013-10-10 10:00:00' , '2013-10-10 11:00:00' getting overlapp - 1 hour
>        '2013-10-10 03:00:00' , '2013-10-10 03:30:00' - .5 hour
>        '2013-10-10 06:30:00' , '2013-10-10 07:30:00'- 1 hour
> ```

The output is group by `sitecode`. and the overlapping date considered only once.
The final output is  required:

> Sitecode 'A' = 2.5 hours

Comment: Are you actually just asking for `The total number of hours that ANY server was down?`  So, if ten servers are down for an hour, that's still just one hour of down time?  And if just one server is down for a different hour, that's still another one hour of down time?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a set of periods and want the overlaps of *all* of them, then the overlaps are going to be between the maximum starttime and the minimum end time.

```
select cast(starttime as date) as thedate, max(starttime), min(endtime)
from #periods
group by cast(starttime as date);
```

This assumes that the start and end are on the same date.  The first just extracts the date from the datetime values (and this may vary depending on the database).  The version here is for SQL Server.

You have no overlaps when `min(endtime)` is less than `max(starttime)`.  So, to get dates with an overlap:

```
select cast(starttime as date) as thedate, max(starttime), min(endtime)
from #periods
group by cast(starttime as date)
having min(endtime) > max(starttime);
```

EDIT:

If you want overlaps within a site code, just add that into the `group by:

```
select sitecode, cast(starttime as date) as thedate, max(starttime), min(endtime)
from #periods
group by sitecode, cast(starttime as date)
having min(endtime) > max(starttime);
```

Comment: But the above amswer wont work for below scenario
create table #period 
(
 Sitecode varchar(20),
 svrname varchar(10),
 StartTime datetime,
 downtimeEnd datetime
) 
go  

insert into #period values 
('A','S1','2013-10-10 07:00:00' , '2013-10-10 07:10:00'), 
('B','S2','2013-10-10 08:10:00' , '2013-10-10 08:20:00'), 
('C','S3','2013-10-10 08:10:00' , '2013-10-10 08:30:00'),
('A','S1','2013-10-10 08:15:00' , '2013-10-10 08:25:00') 

select * from #period

Comment: @anjali.deshetti . . . First, when you have a desire to put code in a comment, think first of editing your question.  It makes it much more readable.  Second, the data in your comment has no overlaps. And the above query will not return anything.

Comment: @anjali.deshetti If you have additional requirements and new sample data, please update your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My wild guess here is that OP wants some overlap between distinct `SiteCode` values. (Periods when all sites were down)

Comment: Hi i apologies, i have edited question hope this time it is clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How will i get to know weather the date is overlapping or not as i want exact hours which mentioned in example

Answer (score 4):

This is one of few examples where it could make sense to use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` (yes it's possible):

```
SELECT MAX(starttime), MIN(endtime)
FROM #period
HAVING MIN(endtime) > MAX(starttime);
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50cfd/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(b.tm) FROM (
  SELECT datediff(second, StartTime, downtimeEnd) AS tm FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT StartTime, downtimeEnd FROM #period 
  ) AS a
) AS b
```

The output will be 9000 Seconds. Than you can convert Seconds into Days, Hours, minutes and seconds.

Hope this helps you.